# why do strings have pointers as there return type?

Tags: pointers

I know what pointers are but when it comes to strings/arrays I get really confused. If someone has an answer or a website that explains it that would be great. For example:

```
char * strncopy (char*dest, char * source, size_t);
```

Why the pointer? what is it pointing to?  Does it a pointer usually store an address?

It is sayed in my textbook that each string building function is of type pointer char*.

Also I was trying to see if I could write a program that would clear things up, but it didn't work. Can someone tell me how to fix it, or what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    

char * getname ()
{
    char name [10];
    scanf ("%s", name);
    return (name);
}    

int main (void)
{
    char name[10];
    printf ("Enter your name\n");
    name[] = getname();
    printf ("Hi %s", name);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: For future reference: If you type "man strncpy" into google, it will immediately send you to a website that answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your getname function, when you return a pointer to the name array because it's allocated on the stack it gets destroyed leaving you with an invalid pointer. Dereferencing such a pointer causes many, many problems.

You should allocate the name array inside of getname on the heap, with malloc/calloc so that when you return the pointer the data won't be destroyed.

With regards to functions like strncpy, they tend to return a pointer to the resulting string; e.g.: strncpy returns a pointer to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer itself represents an address, e.g. if you have a pointer typed `char *pstr`, you can always check the underlying address with `printf("address of my pointer %p\n", pstr);`

In C programming language, a string is an array of `char`. If you have a good knowledge of array and its memory layout, it's not too hard for you to understand c-styled string. Generally speaking, an array in C is a continuous chunk of memory with name of array represent address of the first element in the array. So is string who is a chunk of memory with name of the `char` array address of the first character. In addition, c-styled string terminates with character `\0`, so if you want to manage memory for string yourself, remember one extra byte for the tailing `\0`.

As to your second problem, your `name` in function `getname` is a local variable whose life time ends when function returns. However, you still want to access `name` outside the function which is inappropriate. You can solve this be dynamically allocated memory like in dasblinkenlight's and others' post.

Good luck.